# UITabBarControllerDelegate on two separate UIViewControllers - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have the following code that i'm trying to achieve a "scroll to top" on a UIViewcontroller and "scroll to beginning" on another UIViewController.

The first VC has a table view and the second VC has a collection view.

```
-NearMeViewController-
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
        //....
}
extension NearMeViewController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
        if tabBarIndex == 0 {
            self.nearMeTable.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

-MapSearchViewController-
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
        //....
}

extension MapSearchViewController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
        if tabBarIndex == 2 && requests.mapEventData.count > 0 {
            self.resultsCollectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0),
                                                     at: .left,
                                                     animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

They are both connected to the same UITabBar of course.
The issue is that when i open the app, and i press the tabBarIndex 0 it scrolls to top of the table view.

Then i change VC and i try to press the tabBarIndex 2, so it takes me to the first item of the collection view.

Afterwards I go back to the first VC and when i try to press the tabBarIndex 0, the tableview is not scrolling to top (as it was doing when i first opened the app).

But the second VC with the collection view is working fine.

Any idea why this might happen?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are checking the tabBarController's `.selectedIndex` ... but that is the index of the *currently showing* tab, not the tab you are "on your way to."

More likely, you want to use code similar to this:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

    if let vc = viewController as? MapSearchViewController {
        // user tapped Map Search tab item
    }

    if let vc = viewController as? NearMeViewController {
        // user tapped Near Me tab item
    }

}
```

**Edit:** Here is a simple example, using a subClassed UITabBarController.

Set up your storyboard as normal, creating View Controllers and connecting them as "Tabs", then set the Custom Class of the TabBarController to `MyTabBarController`. This sample code will (hopefully) be easy to follow.

A runnable example is at: https://github.com/DonMag/SWTabBarSubclass

```
//
//  TabBarSample.swift
//

import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // all your normal setup stuff....
    }

    func firstViewSpecific(_ aValue: Int) -> Void {
        print("Passed value is:", aValue)
        // do something with the passed value
    }

}

class NearMeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // all your normal setup stuff....
    }

    func resetMe() -> Void {
        print("resetMe() called in NearMeVC")
        // do whatever you want, such as
        self.nearMeTable.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
    }

}

class MapSearchViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // all your normal setup stuff....
    }

    func resetMe() -> Void {
        print("resetMe() called in MapSearchVC")
        // do whatever you want, such as
        if requests.mapEventData.count > 0 {
            self.resultsCollectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0),
                                                     at: .left,
                                                     animated: true)
        }
    }

}

class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    var myValue = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // make self the UITabBarControllerDelegate
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

        if let vc = viewController as? FirstViewController {
            myValue += 1
            vc.firstViewSpecific(myValue)
            return
        }

        if let vc = viewController as? NearMeViewController {
            vc.resetMe()
            return
        }

        if let vc = viewController as? MapSearchViewController {
            vc.resetMe()
            return
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: and i should put this on which view controller?

Comment: I've subclassed `UITabBarController` for this type of task... Or, create a separate `NSObject, UITabBarControllerDelegate` class and assign it as the delegate... Or, you can put it in the first tab's view controller. I'd recommend subclassing.

Comment: And if i subclass the `UITabBarController` how can i access the tableview or collectionview from the other vcs?

Comment: Subclassing for this seems weird

Comment: @Daij-Djan - As with just about everything, there is more than one way to do it. I'd never claim that "my way is the best way" - so I'm certainly open to hearing opinion.

Comment: Ok so i tried your example but it didnt work at all, cause i dont have any "First VC"... NearMe VC is my first view controller that is loaded! What i tried is to add the function of the first vc to my near me vc with no luck.. any suggestion of what should i change here? P.S. my set up is tabbarcontroller -> navigationcontroller -> viewcontroller.

Comment: *"any suggestion of what should i change here?"* Sure... first suggestion, download and run the example I linked to, and see if you can understand it. If you *can*, then follow that as a guide to implement it in your project. If you *can't*, then go back to how you were doing it to begin with, but use my first answer to fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

viewDidLoad is not being called each time the VC appears but only once (or when it was deallocated before)

the delegate of vc 0 is set only once... and then vc1 is loaded and set as delegate... but then not vc0 again.

to make it work, set the delegate in viewWillAppear.

## note

changing the delegate over and over for this is weird... and checking the index is fragile at best go with DonMag's solution.

Comment: you have a point about `viewDidLoad` ! it works with `viewDidAppear` but I'm not sure i understand the answer of @DonMag

Answer (score 0):

might not apply to all scenarios, check if your VC has been set to

```
self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
```

within your `ViewDidLoad()`